# no module named parsing when importing django models to python script

Tags: python, django

Hi there Im having issues importing my models into my application called `parsing`

project structure looks like:

```
manage.py
enumproject/
db.sqlite3
parsing/
```

with **enumproject/settings.py** I have it in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'parsing',
    'parsing.apps.ParsingConfig',
]
```

**models.py** under parsing/models.py has:

```
from enumproject import models

# Create your models here.

class tbl(models.Model):
    nm=models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    dtAdded=models.DateTimeField()

#etc...
```

im attempting to run **parse.py** from parsing/parse.py

```
from parsing.models import *

#python code here
```

when I run this file, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 8, in <module>
    from parsing.models import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsing'
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in the same folder, then don't use name of the application:

```
from .models import *
```

Comment: when i do this on parse.bash it says:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: 1. do you have `__init__.py` file inside that folder? 2. Do you have `'parsing'` without `#` in INSTALLED_APPS? 3. How do you execute `parse.py` file?